# How to provide access to Distribution List in SharePoint modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, sharepoint-permissions, distribution-lists

There is a distribution list in an organization. In general this is used to send email to large group of staffs. Now I have requirement to provide access to this DL in SharePoint Modern site.

I tried adding into SP site, but got the error saying 'We couldn't find an exact match.

Any workaround on this please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the distribution lists aren't supported methods for assigning SharePoint permissions.

**Solution**:

To resolve this issue, use one of the following methods, depending on your specific scenario:

- If you're using directory synchronization, share the resource with security groups and not with a distribution list.
- Use SharePoint groups. For more information, go to [Customize SharePoint site permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).
- Use Microsoft 365 groups. For more information, go to [Learn about Office 365 Groups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-microsoft-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

**Source**: [SharePoint invitation sent to a distribution list works for only one user](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-invitation-sent-to-a-distribution-list-works-for-only-one-user-4e1f9710-750e-4f5f-b63d-615665ee6773?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)